# Python's fsolve not working

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, solver

I'm currently trying to find the intercept of 2 equations from my code (pasted below). I'm using fsolve and have used it successfully in one part but I can't get it to work for the second.

Confusingly it's not showing up an error, if you paste this code into your notebook and run it you'll see 2 grphs, on the first graph there's a line at an angle which should be stopping at the eqm line.

The section which wont work is def q_eqm(x_q). Thank you for your help

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as opt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

AC_LK = np.array([4.02232,1206.53,220.291])
AC_HK = np.array([4.0854,1348.77,219.976])

P_Tot = 1 # Bara
N_Size = 11 # 1001 = 0.1% accuracy for xA

xf = 0.7
q = 0.7

xA = np.linspace(0,1,N_Size)
yA = np.linspace(0.00,0.00,N_Size)
T = np.linspace(0.00,0.00,N_Size)

x = np.array([xA[0:N_Size],yA[0:N_Size],T[0:N_Size]]) # x[xA,yA,T]

F = np.empty((1))

def xA_T(N):
    xA_Ant = x[0,N]
    def P_Ant(T):

        PA = pow(10,AC_LK[0]-(AC_LK[1]/(T+AC_LK[2])))*xA_Ant
        PB = pow(10,AC_HK[0]-(AC_HK[1]/(T+AC_HK[2])))*(1-xA_Ant)

        F[0] = P_Tot - (PA + PB)

        return F
        return x
    TGuess = [100]
    T = opt.fsolve(P_Ant,TGuess)

    x[2,N] = T

    return x

for N in range(0,len(xA)):
    xA_T(N)
    x[1,N] = pow(10,AC_LK[0]-(AC_LK[1]/(x[2,N]+AC_LK[2])))*x[0,N]/P_Tot

q_int = ((-q*0)/(1-q)) + (xf/(1-q))

Eqm_Poly = np.polyfit(x[0,0:N_Size], x[1,0:N_Size], 6)
q_Poly = np.polyfit([xf,0], [xf,q_int], 1)

F = np.empty((1))

def q_Eqm(x_q):

    y_q = q_Poly[0]*x_q + q_Poly[1]
    eqm_y = (Eqm_Poly[0]*pow(x_q,6)+Eqm_Poly[1]*pow(x_q,5)+Eqm_Poly[2]*pow(x_q,4)+Eqm_Poly[3]*pow(x_q,3)+Eqm_Poly[4]*pow(x_q,2)+Eqm_Poly[5]*pow(x_q,1)+Eqm_Poly[6]*pow(x_q,0))

    F[0] = y_q - eqm_y 
    return F

x_qGuess = [0]
x_q = opt.fsolve(q_Eqm,x_qGuess)


print(x,Eqm_Poly,x_q,q_int)

plt.plot(x[0,0:N_Size],x[1,0:N_Size],'k-',linewidth=1)
plt.plot([xf,xf],[0,xf],'b-',linewidth=1)
plt.plot([xf,x_q],[xf,(q_Poly[0]*x_q + q_Poly[1])],'r-',linewidth=1)
plt.legend(['Eqm','Feed'])
plt.xlabel('xA')
plt.ylabel('yA')
plt.xlim([0.00, 1])
plt.ylim([0.00, 1])
plt.savefig('x.png')
plt.savefig('x.eps')
plt.show()

plt.plot(x[0,0:N_Size],x[2,0:N_Size],'r--',linewidth=3)
plt.plot(x[1,0:N_Size],x[2,0:N_Size],'b--',linewidth=3)
plt.legend(['xA','yA'])
plt.xlabel('Mol Frac')
plt.ylabel('Temp degC')
plt.xlim([0, 1])
plt.savefig('Txy.png')
plt.savefig('Txy.eps')
plt.show()
```

Comment: When I ran this code in under Python 3.6, using Jupyter, I get an error indicating a failure for one of the iteration calculations to progress. This may relate to the problem, not sure. In the top graph I get a red line that crosses the Eqm line.

Comment: Hmm interesting, did it say for which iteration? That red line should be stopping at the eqm line. Thanks

Comment: No. "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py:161: RuntimeWarning: The iteration is not making good progress, as measured by the improvement from the last ten iterations. warnings.warn(msg, RuntimeWarning)".  I am not up to analysing your code, but is it possible the code is fine rather the issue is mathematical in some fashion.

Comment: Ok thank you, I'll try and refine it

Comment: for what it is worth as an apparent new person to posting questions I thought you did well with mastering the process and posting your code. It presents as having taken some time to read and learn how to participate. Good luck, wish you well.

Comment: Thanks, every forums different so I'm glad to know I'm posting along the right guidelines, probably should have said mi using Jupyter and running 3.6

Comment: I disagree to some extent with Cam_Aust. The code is long and complicated which deterred me in the beginning (although the error was easy to spot after looking closer). There is the concept of a [minimal, complete, and verifyable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which makes it easier for others to get into the problem. Often, at least for me, while attempting to create an MCVE the cause and solution to the problem becomes clear before I even have to start asking.

Comment: Yep that would have been additionally helpful. I find posting a question here takes quite a lot more thought than "just posting a quick question" including identifying all the relevant information. Your doing well. Mastering it all is still fresh with me, where as experienced users do seem to forget and be a little quick to judge new people's questions in my view.

Comment: @kazemakase Yes that is valid comment, and I agree, except I note this person is new and did well for their experience. Hence why I did not raise that. It is a little learning curve to get all the things right to be short, succinct, correct use of code blocks etc. Also in this instance, I was able to quickly copy and paste and do as I did to assist.

Comment: @kazemakase Beautiful!

Comment: @Cam_Aust I agree. It is important to encourage new users and give them feedback, both reinforcing good practice and show them where there is potential to improve.

Comment: @kazemakase I am still learning as well, so very conscious of newcomers. Impressed by your insight on the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer turns out to be relatively simple:

```
#F = np.empty((1))  # remove this

def q_Eqm(x_q):
    y_q = q_Poly[0]*x_q + q_Poly[1]
    eqm_y = (Eqm_Poly[0]*pow(x_q,6)+Eqm_Poly[1]*pow(x_q,5)+Eqm_Poly[2]*pow(x_q,4)+Eqm_Poly[3]*pow(x_q,3)+Eqm_Poly[4]*pow(x_q,2)+Eqm_Poly[5]*pow(x_q,1)+Eqm_Poly[6]*pow(x_q,0))
    return y_q - eqm_y
```

[image]

The original code defines a global `F`, which is modified in the function and then returned. So in each iteration the function returns different values but they are the *same* object. This seems to confuse `fsolve` (I guess it internally stores references to the results rather than values). Removing this `F` and simply returning the result of the subtraction resolves the problem.